# Save value of var then pass through function

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing a problem in my code.
I want to save the value of text box in var q, and then I want to pass the value of 'a' and 'z' to checkanswer.php, so I can match my query.

In below code am I on right track to do this or not??

```
function myFunction(a) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = this.responseText;

        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "retrieveQuestion.php?question=" +a, true);
    xhttp.send();
    var q="<td><input type='text' name='answer' placeholder='submit your answer here'/></td>" ;
    document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML=q;
    var z="<td align='center'><input type='button' value='submit' onclick ='myfunc1(a,q);'/></td>";
    document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML=z;
}

function myfunc1(q1,a1)
{
    xhttp.open("GET", "checkanswer.php?question=" +q1 + "&a1=" +a1, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Did you run your code? Did it work as expected?

Comment: You do not have a callback in the second GET

Comment: Add id parameter to the input and get it's value in `myfunc1`.